# Issues with replacing current values in a dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to replace the values for each abbreviation of a country in each column to its actual name (i.e. "USA" to "United States"). The data frame is over 10,000 lines. I have tried many methods, including the code below, and still have not been able to update the value. I also tried the same statement with %in%.

```
starbucks_data = read.csv("starbucksdata.csv", header = TRUE)
starbucks_data1 = starbucks_data[!(is.na(starbucks_data)),]
new_starbucks_data = starbucks_data1[,c("Brand","City", "Country")]

new = data.frame(new_starbucks_data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
new$Country[new$Country == "AD"] <- "Andorra"
new
```

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8F4R.png)

This is what it looks like with the above method. I get the error "invalid factor level, NA generated", but I thought the stringsAsFactors = FALSE would solve that issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You country abreviations are probably coded as factors. Convert your abreviations to character first or change your `read.csv` line to `read.csv("starbucksdata.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: thank you, that did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem starts when you use `read.csv` - that function will automatically turn all strings into factors.  When you create the new data frame, not converting any strings into factors doesn't matter - because they are already factors.

You have several options:

1. use `read_csv` from somewhere in the `tidyverse` suite of packages - it specifically doesn't do this.
2. add option `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to your `read.csv` fuction.
3. change the levels of the factors instead of the values

For the last option, (again) multiple options exist.  The base R method is to do:

```
levels(new$country) <- c("new1", "new2", ...)
```

(replacing the `...` with your list of desired names).
This can be a bit dangerous, since you have to line them up perfectly to get the right result.  An alternative using the `forcats` package (part of `tidyverse` uses a function `fct_recode` to explicitly recode each factor:

```
new$country <- fct_recode(
  Andorra = "AD",
  `United States` = "USA")
```

etc.  (You might need to play with the quoting when spaces are involved.  I did not test that aspect of this.)